# How can I check if my session is the first boot session of the user?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to check if the current session is the first time that the user is used. Is it possible to do this in Bash or another language?

I’m using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: What's the context or use-case here? For a one-shot situation, you'll probably know it already, so I'm wondering if you're thinking about doing this in some kind of installer or when cloning multiple systems. If it's enough to answer "is this the first time the system is booted _with this software_", then that should be relatively easy to do by just creating some file on the first run and checking that.

Comment: You can check the `/var/log/syslog` and look for the kernel boot command line.  Use `grep 'Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=' /var/log/syslog`